# RelatedObjectDoesNotExist in Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I am working on ecommerce site and I get this error:

> "Exception Type:  RelatedObjectDoesNotExist Exception Value: User has
> no customer."

models.py

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
```

views.py

```
def cart(request):
    customer=request.user.customer
    order,created=Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer,complete=False)
    items=order.orderitem_set.all()
    context={
        'items':items
    }
```

thanks beforehand.

Comment: You simply don't have Customer record for  that particular User as error states

Comment: OneToOne field does not automatically create the related object.  User should be created, attached and the customer should be saved to the DB before instantiating any Orders.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add related_name in OneToOneField

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, related_name="customer')
```